# plot with external variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, external

I'm using dplyr to make this code work for an external variable:

```
#This is the original code
 library(dplyr)
 library(ggplot2)
 k=c(0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3)
 dfsex1<-df %>%
   group_by(gender) %>%
   summarise(FreqRisk=mean(Freq)+k*sd(Freq), .groups = 'drop')
 ggplot(dfsex1, aes(x=k, y=FreqRisk, group=as.factor(gender),
   color=as.factor(gender))) + 
   geom_line(aes(size=gender),size = 0.5)+
   scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,3),breaks=c(0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3))+
   scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,3),breaks=c(0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3))+
   scale_color_manual(name="Gender",labels = c("F", "M"), values = c("red", "blue"))+
   ggtitle("2012-2015")+
   labs(x="k",y="Riskmeasure")+
   theme_bw()+
   theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

It returns the error "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (14): x
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred."
How would I do this?

Comment: Difficult to answer without seeing some or all of the data in `df` _e.g._ the output from `dput(df)`. But the `x` and `y` arguments to `ggplot` should always be dataframe column names, not separate vectors, for best results.

Comment: Your issue is that you are applying `k` to the `x` aesthetic, but that only has 7 values, whereas your dataframe `dfsex1` has 14 based on the error message.  `ggplot2` will check the dataframe (here `dfsex1` first for the value you apply to the aesthetics, and if not, it will search the local environment and finds `k`.  It's certainly possible to supply an external variable/vector, but it has to have the same length as the number of rows in the dataframe.

Comment: difficult to follow the pipes  as the last one is  group_by(gender) %>%???